# Find the maximum number of distinct graphs

Tags: graph

The question is: How many distinct non-oriented graphs, with 6 nodes, numbered from 1 to 6, can be constructed so that node 2 has degree 1. Two graphs are distinct if their adjacency matrices are different.

I know some notions about graphs and I thought that I would have to find out the number of distinct non-oriented graphs that can be built with 5 nodes and then multiply that by the number 5.

The problem is that I can't figure it out because I don't really understand the notion of degree in a graph.

I would appreciate your help. Thanks!!

Comment: Degree is just the number of connections a node has.

Comment: this is a question about graph-theory not about c++ code

Comment: `I know some notions about graphs and I thought that I would have to find out the number of distinct non- oriented graphs that can be built with 5 nodes and then multiply that by the number 5.` The flaw in that is that some of the five node graphs will be symmetrical, so adding an extra node won't always result in a distinct six node graph. Although I am assuming that the node numbering is not part of the graphs identity and looking at your defintion I'm not sure that's true.

Comment: Thanks!  Somehow, at first, this question sounded like a problem where I could use combinations, but I'm not really sure ...
I thought that  if I asked this question  I could understand better how graphs work in c++, it is a very vast area.

Comment: I think node 2 would have to be adjacent to nodes 1, 3, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: So there would be some graphs where node 2, it would be adjacent to node 1, some other graphs where it would be adjacent to node 3.....and so on, at last there would be some graphs where it would be adjacent to node 6. This is what I am trying to figure out, a formula to calculate the number of nodes in these groups.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration again, some aspects of this problem, I have reached a conclusion.

There are 5 nodes that can form the distinct graphs, because 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 are, possibly, the adjacent nodes of node 2.

With these five nodes, there can be 2 ^ 10 distinct unoriented graphs, which is 2 ^ (5*2).The logic is that 5 is the number of nodes that are adjacent to node 2, and 2 is the number of connections that each node has, because the graph is undirected. And this number represents the graphs that can be built, in order to respect the condition.

At the end, the only operation to be done is to multiply (2 ^ 10) * 5.

So all the graphs should have 6 nodes, there is no difference between the number of nodes in the number of graphs that are possible.

The notion of symmetry of a graph usually refers to a graph that reflects the behaviour of a mathematical function; in this context, of mathematical functions, it is True that a graph can be symmetric with respect to a line.

https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=MathApps/SymmetriesOfAGraph